# What is the recommended way to integrate Hamcrest into Eclipse's JUnit?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, junit, hamcrest

Is there a recommended way to integrate Hamcrest into the JUnit configuration in Eclipse? Currently Eclipse's JUnit comes with Hamcrest-core only. I want to edit that configuration to include Hamcrest-all. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to stop you adding hamcrest as a JAR to your eclipse project's build path. If there's one packaged with eclipse (and I didn't realise there was, but fair enough), then it's just there as a convenience.

Comment: Yes, I could always add it as a library, but I was hoping to find a way to embed it into JUnit's configuration, so that it's automatically added to all (existing and new) projects that use JUnit.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Hamcrest adds some of the same classes that JUnit is providing, thus leading to SecurityExceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems using hamcrest-all and junit-dep - you then need jMock an easymock and ant.tasks

If you just want more matchers, add hamcrest-library (along with the junit and hamcrest core you get from Eclipse)

Shouldn't this question have the "hamcrest" tag?

Comment: The tag didn't exist when I created the question IIRC. I've added it now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: After I posted this I ran into a problem with this approach. I get a SecurityException. Apparently this is because the Eclipse hamcrest-core is signed but the hamcrest-library I added isn't. Supposedly the solution is to put the unsigned one first in the build path but that didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit goes in two [distributions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/junit/files/): with Hamcrest (junit-4.6.jar) and without Hamcrest (junit-dep-4.6.jar). If I understand your question correctly, you need to specify junit-4.6.jar in JUnit configuration. I think it is possible in Eclipse (I use another IDE).

Comment: It seems to me that JUnit only includes hamcrest-core, while I am trying to integrate hamcrest-all into Eclipse.

Comment: You're right. Probably you can build your own junit.jar with embedded classes from hamcrest-all.jar and replace junit.jar in JUnit eclipse plugin with it. I'm not sure it is a good idea, but you can try.

Comment: Yes, I believe this would work, but I don't think it's the "recommended" way of doing it. :)